# How to get coloured terminal over ssh?

Tags: command-line, ssh

When I connect over ssh to remote hosts everything is just a single font/color. I would like to have colours like I do locally e.g. green for executable and blue for symlinks etc. And such that when I run $ git diff on the ssh host it shows me diff with colours =)

Comment: Is that an Ubuntu server you're connecting to?

Comment: @stefano-palazzo: to Debian.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Because it was xterm on the server, I figured something was wrong with `.bashrc`

And indeed! `ls --color=auto` works only when you are connected to TTY. Changing everything to simply `--color` in `.bashrc` on the remote host and everything is in pretty colours now.

Comment: It would help this answer a lot if you said *where* you put --color=auto. .bashrc on the server? What commands?

Comment: Since this is an old question which is still relevant, I just wanted to add that on Ubuntu systems, the default .bashrc has a case statement which defines which terms are allowed color. If you find the "case "$TERM$" in" line in your .bashrc, adding "xterm) color_prompt=yes;;" will also enable color.
Also you can uncomment the "force_color_prompt=yes" line to globally enable it always.

Comment: it was Mike E 's comment that fixed it for me,

Comment: I'm confused. What does it mean to "changing everything to simply --color"? Can I see an example?

Comment: Are you guys talking about the local host, the remote host or both?

Comment: @Adam the remote host.

Comment: Can someone improve this answer and show an example ?

Comment: This answer was silly, it never said where to put --color. So I fixed it.

Comment: @rjurney There are at least four .bashrc files in different locations "on the server" I looked at.

Answer (score 41):

This worked for me:

```
ssh -t my_host my_command
```

`-t` was the key. [Explained](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=ssh+-t+my_host+my_command):

```
-t      Force pseudo-tty allocation.  This can be used to execute arbitrary screen-based programs on a
        remote machine, which can be very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services.  Multiple -t
        options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.
```

Comment: This works perfectly, and is very convenient for one off tasks. Thanks!

Comment: I lost the colorize when I did `su -` command in the ssh connection prompt

Comment: This is the missing link if adding `--color` alone doesn't help.

Answer (score 33):

Seems like colors were already set in `~/.bashrc` for me and the issue is that ssh does not use the bashrc file. You can use bashrc in your ssh session by adding the following to `~/.bash_profile`:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
      . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

Comment: This worked for me, and was a simple and efficient way to get it done!

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS this worked for me + Miek-e's answer.

Comment: Bongo! This worked for me. Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows Terminal.

Comment: Thanks! For me, it's just adding `[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile"` into `~/.bash_profile`. My `~/.profile` includes above recommended `~/.bashrc` condition

Answer (score 24):

Since the colors worked fine while being loggged in directly, I just un-uncommented the line `force_color_prompt=yes` in the file `~/.bashrc`, that gave me colors over ssh, too:

```
# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
force_color_prompt=yes
```

(Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)

Comment: This also works for Debian 10 (buster). If you're ssh-ing into your server and you don't have colors when TERM=xterm-kitty or others this is what you need to do to get colors. The lines the above answer mentions should be in your ~/.bashrc after initial Debian install

Answer (score 8):

What's the content of your XTERM env variable on the server when you connect to it?

```
~ > export | grep -i term
TERM=xterm
```

Comment: $ export | grep -i term
declare -x TERM="xterm"

Answer (score 6):

In my case, the missing part was to have colored ls, grep, etc. which can be added by adding aliases to the .bashrc file:

```
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
```

etc.

Answer (score 3):

I tried changing `~./bashrc` settings (both on local and remote server), but it did not seem to work.

Then I noticed that `~/.bashrc` of remote server does not even get executed if I connect to it over ssh. So I made `~/.bashrc` of remote server to execute by **puttinng `if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc fi` in remote server's `~/.bash_profile`.** (based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820517/bashrc-at-ssh-login).

So this solution did not require changing any `~/bashrc` files directly but it did require changing `~/bash_profile` file of remote server so that `~/bashrc` file of remote server got executed.

Comment: Ubuntu uses `.profile` and not `.bash_profile` by default, and the default `.profile` does source `.bashrc`.

Comment: That is correct. But does `.profile` get executed by default when logging in through ssh?

Comment: Yes. Provided you didn't override it using `.bash_profile`, bash runs `.profile` when started as a login shell. And SSH starts bash as a login shell.

Comment: It is correct that `~/.profile` is not read if `~/.bash_profile` exists. But doesn't `~/.bash_profile` exist on Ubuntu by default?

Comment: See my first comment again. No, it doesn't. Ubuntu uses `.profile`.

Comment: Ok, you are correct. I had quite a few remote AWS Ubuntu instances running and all of them seemed to have `.bash_profile` file (without me remembering putting them there). It turns out that other people did actually create them there. So in one instance it broke my terminal colors. So much for unexpected consequences.

Comment: Sigh. Being  AWS, I suppose graphical login isn't done. Or the other users might have noticed different behaviour, for example, if they'd changed the `PATH` in `.bash_profile` but not in `.profile` or vice versa.

Comment: This is a good clarification. But I am not sure how useful this answer is in the end because I realized that I somehow did not notice that one of the earlier answers actually described the same solution (just with less detail). So this probably should have been just a clarification comment.

Answer (score 3):

There is a comment from "Mike E" above that contained the answer for me, but it is not only hard to read, it is kind of hard to figure out what he means if you don't use `.bashrc` a lot - and I don't.

After screwing around a bit, I got the desired results by changing the following lines in `~/.bashrc` on the machine I was logging into with ssh:

```
# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac
```

to:

```
# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
    xterm) color_prompt=yes;;
esac
```

I am thinking I could have just added "|xterm" after "color" in the first line, or dug around and figure out why ssh was using "xterm" instead of "xterm-color" and change that, but this works and I have other things to do now.

Answer (score 3):

In my situation, I recently installed `chef-local` and it asked me to add a line to `.bash_profile`. When I sign in, `.bashrc` never loads anymore, because it saw `.bash_profile`.

What I did was to add a line in `.bash_profile`:

```
source .bashrc
export PATH="/opt/chefdk/embedded/bin:$PATH"
```

I logged out and back in and got my colored terminal right away.

Comment: +1 for similar situation. Just adding `source .bashrc` to .bash_profile fixed it in Ubuntu server 18.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

I was losing my color when connecting via a proxy because `TERM=dumb` so I fixed it:

```
ssh myproxy "ssh pi@localhost -p 5000 -tt 'TERM=xterm bash'"
```

Comment: You should allocate a terminal on the first connection as well, if you're going to do that.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me: just open your .bashrc file in your $HOME folder, and uncomment the line `force_color_prompt=yes`

Answer (score 0):

```
cd
cat << 'EOF' >color_terminals_over_ssh.sh
#!/bin/bash
#Must pass either enable or disable to script
#./color_terminals_over_ssh.sh enable

DO=$1

if [[ $DO = "enable" ]]
then
 sudo sed -i '/force_color_prompt=yes/s/^#//g' /home/*/.bashrc
 sudo sed -i '/force_color_prompt=yes/s/^#//g' /root/.bashrc
 sudo su
elif [[ $DO = "disable" ]]
then
 sudo sed -i '/force_color_prompt=no/s/^/#/g' /home/*/.bashrc
 sudo sed -i '/force_color_prompt=no/s/^/#/g' /root/.bashrc
 sudo su
fi

cat ~/.bashrc | grep force_color_prompt=yes

EOF
chmod +x color_terminals_over_ssh.sh
./color_terminals_over_ssh.sh enable
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue after creating a new user on Linux (Ubuntu). Setting `force_color_prompt=yes` didn't do it for me.

I forgot to specify the shell, so it went for the default `/bin/sh`, redirecting to `/bin/dash` apparently on my distribution. When manually setting it to `/bin/bash` everything worked out of the box.

So in my case I could have used the `-s` flag when adding the user (so `useradd -s /bin/bash ...` to specify the shell. Instead I used `chsh -s /bin/bash` to set it after creation.

Answer (score 0):

just run

```
sudo chsh -s /bin/bash <user>
```