# Turn on color scheme in bash

Tags: bash, ssh, colors

I have a VPS with ubuntu linux on it.

```
$ ssh ghopper@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
ghopper@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-134-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage
New release '18.04.1 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.

Last login: Wed Sep 19 16:52:58 2018 from 178.140.210.120
ghopper@114744:~$ env

LC_PAPER=ru_RU.UTF-8
XDG_SESSION_ID=409
LC_ADDRESS=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=ru_RU.UTF-8
TERM=xterm-256color
SHELL=/bin/bash
SSH_CLIENT=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 51616 22
LC_NUMERIC=ru_RU.UTF-8
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
USER=ghopper
LC_TELEPHONE=ru_RU.UTF-8
MAIL=/var/mail/ghopper
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
LC_IDENTIFICATION=ru_RU.UTF-8
PWD=/home/ghopper
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=ru_RU.UTF-8
SHLVL=1
HOME=/home/ghopper
LOGNAME=ghopper
SSH_CONNECTION=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 51616 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 22
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
LC_TIME=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_NAME=ru_RU.UTF-8
_=/usr/bin/env
ghopper@114744:~$ tail -n 16 ~/.bashrc
function color_my_prompt {
    local __user_and_host="\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h"
    local __cur_location="\[\033[01;34m\]\w"
    local __git_branch_color="\[\033[31m\]"
    local __git_branch='`git branch 2> /dev/null | grep -e ^* | sed -E  s/^\\\\\*\ \(.+\)$/\(\\\\\1\)\ /`'
    local __prompt_tail="\[\033[35m\]$"
    local __last_color="\[\033[00m\]"
    export PS1="$__user_and_host $__cur_location $__git_branch_color$__git_branch$__prompt_tail$__last_color "
}
color_my_prompt

export IGNOREEOF=10

export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

The problem is that there aren't colors in the terminal. At all!

But, after I run `/bin/bash` they appears.

```
ghopper@114744:~$ /bin/bash
ghopper@114744 ~ $ env
LC_PAPER=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=ru_RU.UTF-8
XDG_SESSION_ID=409
LC_MONETARY=ru_RU.UTF-8
SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM=xterm-256color
IGNOREEOF=10
SSH_CLIENT=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 51616 22
LC_NUMERIC=ru_RU.UTF-8
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
USER=ghopper
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:m ... 0;36:*.xspf=00;36:
LC_TELEPHONE=ru_RU.UTF-8
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
MAIL=/var/mail/ghopper
LC_IDENTIFICATION=ru_RU.UTF-8
PWD=/home/ghopper
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=ru_RU.UTF-8
PS1=\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h \[\033[01;34m\]\w \[\033[31m\]`git branch 2> /dev/null | grep -e ^* | sed -E  s/^\\\\\*\ \(.+\)$/\(\\\\\1\)\ /`\[\033[35m\]$\[\033[00m\] 
HOME=/home/ghopper
SHLVL=2
LOGNAME=ghopper
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
SSH_CONNECTION=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 51616 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
LC_TIME=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_NAME=ru_RU.UTF-8
_=/usr/bin/env
```

How can I get colored terminal by default?

Comment: I just created ~/.bash_profile file as described by the [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/608096/769273)